# Запись в БД Access данных

Tags: c#

Такая ситуация, имеется код:

```
private void signWashBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default["ButName"] = urNameText.Text + urNumberText.Text + urNumberCarText.Text + setTimeDate.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=CarWashBase.mdb;");

        String sql = "INSERT INTO CarsWashing (name_man, number_man, number_car) Values ('" + urNameText.Text + "', '" + urNumberText.Text + "', '" + urNumberCarText.Text + "'); UPDATE CarsWashing SET date_time = '" + setTimeDate.Text + "'"; "UPDATE CarsWashing SET date_time = '" + setTimeDate.Text + "'";
        //sql = "UPDATE CarsWashing SET date_time = '" + setTimeDate.Text + "'";

        this.AUD(sql);
    }
```

Вопрос в чем, когда я пытаюсь в строку String sql вставить две команды "Insert ... ; Update";, то при компиляции пишет такая ошибка: В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения назначения, вызова, инкремента, декремента и создания нового объекта.

Ибо мне нужно, чтобы все данные записывались сразу.

Answer (score 2):

Вы напутали со строками и кавычками, и получилось:

```
String sql = "..."; "...";
```

Вторая строка висит в воздухе и компилятор не знает, что с ней делать. Вторая строка там вообще не нужна.

Вы точно хотите изменить все записи в таблице `CarsWashing`?

Comment: Вторую строку я специально в комментирование поставил, ибо такой способ не работал

Comment: Да, у меня 3 TextBox'a, и один элемент DateTimePicker (setTimeDate)

Comment: @АртурТимиров Не торопитесь. Прочитайте мой ответ еще раз. Потом внимательно посмотрите на Ваш код.

Comment: Блин, возможно прозвучит как отмазка, но я не понимаю. Просто идет 3-й час ночи, и у меня минимум знаний в языке. Пытаюсь понимать, но не всегда получается.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ от @Igor правильный, можете отметить его ответ галочкой

```csharp
setTimeDate.Text + "'"; "UPDATE ..."
//                    ^ здесь ошибка
```

Забыли закомментировать, попробуйте вот так

```csharp
setTimeDate.Text + "'"; //"UPDATE ..."
```